# How to pass terraform outputs variables into ansible as vars_files?

Tags: ansible, terraform

I am provisioning AWS infrastructure using terraform and want to pass variables such as `aws_subnet_id` and `aws_security_id` into ansible playbook using `vars_file` (don't know if there is any other way though). How can I do that?

Answer (score 24):

I use Terraform `local_file` to create an Ansible vars_file. I add a `tf_` prefix to the variable names to make it clear that they originate in Terraform:

```
# Export Terraform variable values to an Ansible var_file
resource "local_file" "tf_ansible_vars_file_new" {
  content = <<-DOC
    # Ansible vars_file containing variable values from Terraform.
    # Generated by Terraform mgmt configuration.

    tf_environment: ${var.environment}
    tf_gitlab_backup_bucket_name: ${aws_s3_bucket.gitlab_backup.bucket}
    DOC
  filename = "./tf_ansible_vars_file.yml"
}
```

Run `terraform apply` to create Ansible var_file `tf_ansible_vars_file.yml` containing Terraform variable values:

```yaml
# Ansible vars_file containing variable values from Terraform.
# Generated by Terraform mgmt configuration.

tf_environment: "mgmt"
tf_gitlab_backup_bucket_name: "project-mgmt-gitlab-backup"
```

Add `tf_ansible_vars_file.yml` to your Ansible playbook:

```yaml
  vars_files:
    - ../terraform/mgmt/tf_ansible_vars_file.yml
```

Now, in Ansible the variables defined in this file will contain values from Terraform.

Obviously, this means that you must run Terraform before Ansible. But it won't be so obvious to all your Ansible users. Add assertions to your Ansible playbook to help the user figure out what to do if a `tf_` variable is missing:

```yaml
- name: Check mandatory variables imported from Terraform
  assert:
    that:
      - tf_environment is defined
      - tf_gitlab_backup_bucket_name is defined
    fail_msg: "tf_* variable usually defined in '../terraform/mgmt/tf_ansible_vars_file.yml' is missing"
```

UPDATE: An earlier version of this answer used a Terraform template. Experience shows that the template file is error prone and adds unnecessarily complexity. So I moved the template file to the `content` of the `local_file`.

Comment: Hi @John McGehee i tried this, but it is not working, i have a separate `variables.tf` file as well as `terraform.tfvars` as well. in the `.tpl` file i gave as below `tf_share_location: "${share_location}"` . In render i used the same as you used. But i get the following error `Error: failed to render : <template_file>:1,23-37: Unknown variable; There is no variable named "share_location".

  on terraform_render.tf line 2, in data "template_file" "tf_ansible_vars_file":
   2: data "template_file" "tf_ansible_vars_file" {`

Comment: Here is my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61664836/terraform-outputs-to-ansible

Comment: Btw in case you want to run terraform and Ansible in the same CI, keep in mind that `terraform apply` will create that file, `terraform plan` will not, which basically means that you have to commit the variables file in the repository in order to have `ansible --check` in pull requests not failing.

Comment: @John McGehee Hi, did u declare "var.environment" in variable.tf file?

Comment: @John McGehee This code is not creating file for me. Terraform does not throw error but I can't see file created in my Jenkins node. I have created an empty file and pushed it to git so that there is vars folder in my ansible dir and it can write this yml contents to this blank file in vard dir.

Answer (score 8):

Since I want to run both `terraform plan` and `ansible --check` in a pull request with a CI, I've decided to go with `terraform output`.

Basically this is how I run my Ansible now and it gets all outputs from terraform :

With the following output

```
// output.tf
output "tf_gh_deployment_status_token" {
  value       = var.GH_DEPLOYMENT_STATUS_TOKEN
  sensitive   = true
}
```

Running a bit modified `terraform output` parsed with `jq` :

```
$ terraform output --json | jq 'with_entries(.value |= .value)'
{
  "tf_gh_deployment_status_token": "<some token>"
}
```

This makes it great to run with `--extra-args` with Ansible :

```
$ ansible-playbook \
  -i ./inventory/production.yaml \
  ./playbook.yaml \
  --extra-vars "$(terraform output --json | jq 'with_entries(.value |= .value)')"
```

Now I can use `{{ tf_gh_deployment_status_token }}` anywhere in my playbook.

Comment: Hi, did u declare "var.GH_DEPLOYMENT_STATUS_TOKEN" in variable.tf file?

Comment: yes I did

```
variable "GH_DEPLOYMENT_STATUS_TOKEN" {
  type        = string
  description = "The deployment status token from GitHub, that will update the release of the repository"
  sensitive   = true
}
```

Answer (score 5):

terraform outputs are an option, or you can just use something like:

```
provisioner "local-exec" {
  command = "ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=\"False\" ansible-playbook -u ${var.ssh_user} --private-key=\"~/.ssh/id_rsa\" --extra-vars='{"aws_subnet_id": ${aws_terraform_variable_here}, "aws_security_id": ${aws_terraform_variable_here} }' -i '${azurerm_public_ip.pnic.ip_address},' ansible/deploy-with-ansible.yml"
}
```

or you can do a sed thing ... as a local provisioner to update the var file..

or you can use terraform outputs.... your preference....

Answer (score 3):

I highly recommend this script. It works well and is maintained by Cisco and will give you more flexibility.

https://github.com/CiscoCloud/terraform.py

Comment: This is nice! Didn't know it existed.

Answer (score 2):

Use terraform outputs - https://www.terraform.io/intro/getting-started/outputs.html (it is not clear if you are using it already)

Then using command like `terraform output ip`, you can then use those values in your scripts to generate or populate other files like inventory files or vars_file.

Another option is to use terraform templates and render your files like inventory files from terraform itself and then use it from Ansible.