# How do you output variables to Ansible?

Tags: ansible, terraform

I followed the answer here in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60573761/13081977) and 
I have created a `template` file `tf_ansible_vars_file.yml.tpl` like below

```
tf_share_location: "${share_location}"
```

and a `terra_render.tf` like below

```
# Define an Ansible var_file containing Terraform variable values
data "template_file" "tf_ansible_vars_file" {
  template = "${file("/home/deployment_root/app4/tf_ansible_vars_file.yml.tpl")}"
  vars = {
    share_location = var.share_location
    # gitlab_backup_bucket_name = aws_s3_bucket.gitlab_backup.bucket
  }
}

# Render the Ansible var_file containing Terrarorm variable values
resource "local_file" "tf_ansible_vars_file" {
  content  = data.template_file.tf_ansible_vars_file.rendered
  filename = "/home/deployment_root/app4/tf_ansible_vars_file.yml"
}
```

I already have a `variables.tf` file in which i have declared that variable

```
variable "share_location" {
    type = string

}
```

and in the `terraform.tfvars` gave the value as `null`

`share_location = null`

when i run `terraform apply` i get the below error

```
Error: failed to render : <template_file>:1,23-37: Unknown variable; There is no variable named "share_location".

  on terra_render.tf line 2, in data "template_file" "tf_ansible_vars_file":
   2: data "template_file" "tf_ansible_vars_file" {
```

My understanding is it will create a file as mentioned in that answer, but it is not working.

How do you output variables to Ansible?

Comment: You assigned the `null` type as the value for the variable, so unless there is some unusual type casting occurring during rendering, this is not going to work. If you do not want to use the variable, then you can just remove it from the template.

Comment: This is confusing, if i remove that value, it is asking for a value, am i not asking terraform to generate one for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the below code, instead of `var.share_location` , i need to give the variable that i used in `terraform` in my case 
`${data.azurerm_storage_account.new.name}/sharename`  and after that i can remove that from `variables.tf` as well as `terraform.tfvars` as i am getting the value generated. Thanks

**Old code :**

```
data "template_file" "tf_ansible_vars_file" {
  template = "${file("/home/deployment_root/app4/tf_ansible_vars_file.yml.tpl")}"
  vars = {
    share_location = var.share_location
    # gitlab_backup_bucket_name = aws_s3_bucket.gitlab_backup.bucket
  }
}
```

**New Code:**

```
# Define an Ansible var_file containing Terraform variable values
data "template_file" "tf_ansible_vars_file" {
  template = "${file("/home/deployment_root/app4/tf_ansible_vars_file.yml.tpl")}"
  vars = {
    share_location = "${data.azurerm_storage_account.new.name}/sharename"
    # gitlab_backup_bucket_name = aws_s3_bucket.gitlab_backup.bucket
  }
}
```

Comment: Even tho it worked for you, I am downvoting because your answer will confuse others. Please revise it.

Comment: @doc_noob Hi, did u declare var.share_location in variables.tf?

Answer (score 2):

If you are generating a supported format like YAML, you do not need a template file.

You can generate YAML directly from Terraform data structures as follows:

```
resource "local_file" "tf_ansible_vars_file" {
  content  = yamlencode(
    {
      tf_share_location = var.share_location
      # gitlab_backup_bucket_name = aws_s3_bucket.gitlab_backup.
    }
  )
  filename = var.ansible_vars_filename
}

variable "ansible_vars_filename" {
    type = string
    default = "/home/deployment_root/app4/tf_ansible_vars_file.yml"
}
```

Applying that with `-var="share_location=example_location"` will yield a file like this:

```
"tf_share_location": "example_location"
```

Whether or not the quoting the configuration variable names matters depends on Ansible. It shouldn't as it's still valid YAML. Terraform's **yamlencode** quotes those regardless of whether they need to be, which is regrettable.

I have extracted **ansible_vars_filename** to a variable as you may want to make that configurable.

I have also left in the commented out **gitlab_backup_bucket_name** as adding it to the YAML file is as simple as uncommenting it.

You can learn more about **yamlencode** here:

https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/yamlencode.html