# Read file and save output to local_file

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm trying to read the content of a file on an azurerm_linux_virtual_machine and save it to a local_file so that an ansible playbook can reference it later. Currently the .tf looks like this

```
resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "vm" {
name                  = myvm
location              = myzone
resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.azureansibledemo.name
network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.myterraformnic.id]
size                  = "Standard_DS1_v2"

os_disk {
    name              = "storage"
    caching           = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type = "Premium_LRS"
}

source_image_reference {
    publisher = "Canonical"
    offer     = "UbuntuServer"
    sku       = "16.04-LTS"
    version   = "latest"
}

computer_name  = myvm
admin_username = "azureuser"
disable_password_authentication = true
custom_data = base64encode(file("telnet.sh"))

admin_ssh_key {
    username       = "azureuser"
    public_key     = tls_private_key.ansible_ssh_key.public_key_openssh
}

boot_diagnostics {
    storage_account_uri = azurerm_storage_account.mystorageaccount.primary_blob_endpoint
}


}

output "myoutput" {
    value = file("/tmp/output.yml")
}

resource "local_file" "testoutput" {
  content = <<-DOC
    ${file("/tmp/output.yml")}
    DOC
    filename = "test.yml"
}
```

But when i run terraform plan i get the following error

```
Error: Invalid function argument

  on main.tf line 181, in resource "local_file" "testoutput":
 181:     ${file("/tmp/output.yml")}

Invalid value for "path" parameter: no file exists at /tmp/output.yml; this
function works only with files that are distributed as part of the
configuration source code, so if this file will be created by a resource in
this configuration you must instead obtain this result from an attribute of
that resource.
```

The output myoutput is fine and returns no errors, this only occurs when i add in the resource local_file. Is there a way to get the output of a file to a local_file?

Answer (score 0):

Copping remote files to local is [not supported](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/3379) by TF.

The workaround is to use `scp` in `local-exec` as shown [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/3379#issuecomment-413166503). For example:

```
provisioner "local-exec" {
  command = "scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -i ${var.openstack_keypair} ubuntu@${openstack_networking_floatingip_v2.wr_manager_fip.address}:~/client.token ."
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the response. Would there be a way to use the output to create a new local_file? Similar to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40353666/how-to-pass-terraform-outputs-variables-into-ansible-as-vars-files?

Comment: @CEamonn You could develop your own [External Data Source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external/latest/docs/data-sources/data_source) which would fetch the file and then you could use it anywhere you wish in your TF code.

Comment: @CEamonn How did it go? Did you manaeg to use external data source or scp?